# Scaling only images in HTMLDocument/JEditorPane?

Tags: java, swing

I have a read-only JEditorPane arrangement using approximately the zoom/scaling solution detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9136755/1145938), except trimmed down a bit and only scaling the body element. This is working quite well, except that Swing has different default styles than anything else, causing images to *seem* twice as big as they ought to be. This isn't caused by the scaling modifications, Swing just wants to render text at a much smaller size than if the document is opened in an actual browser or LibreOffice. Obviously, zooming the entire document also scales up the images.

What I would like to do is introduce a new option, that scales images in a document separately. I figured the logical approach would be to apply the same basic concepts to an ImageView. This does not work in the least. At all. In a variety of ways.

Unfortunately, that leaves me at a loss. I have only two requirements, really; the image element its self must scale properly (meaning anything below or beside it is moved based on the new size, not just scaling the visible graphic), and it must update on-the-fly after the document has been processed by checking [document].getProperty("IMG_ZOOM") in the same way the overall body scaling does.

Any leads on this matter would be quite appreciated.

Comment: _Obviously, zooming the entire document also scales up the images._ Did you try adding a CSS property to increase the font size?

Comment: @BackSlash Yes, but LibreOffice already applies inline styles, so I'm sure you know the result.